# How to use array object value in next thread group using bean-shell assertion?

Tags: jmeter

[image]I am using BeanShell assertion to passing value to next thread group. Now I wanted to use that value in next thread group. I am using set Property function and I can see in logs those values stored in variable.

Answer (score -1):

Given you set some property value via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) like:

```
${__setProperty(foo,bar,)}
```

you can read it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(foo,)}
```

[image]

---

If you want to fetch the value in a script - you can use `props` shorthand like:

```
String myValue = props.get("foo");
```

[image]

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to JSR223 Assertion. If you're setting the property value from the script - don't inline JMeter Function, use the aforementioned `props` shorthand instead like:

```
props.put("foo", "bar"); // this creates "foo" property with the value of "bar"
```

You should be able to re-use the same code. Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article which covers your use case in particular and few more common tasks in general for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, But in my case as per your example inside "foo" there are multiple values (It's array) and I want to access those array value in next thread group. Have tried with like ${__property(foo_1)} but it won't work for me.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Have added image in question please see it. Into logs line number 31 where I can see all values inside questionid as a array. Now I want to access those value one by one for next request.

Comment: This does not answer the question. As @VimalHirpara has alluded to, the question asks for passing an array of values via property to another thread group.